# setting up rsync to sync a server

Tags: centos, rsync

I have a server with 30gb of content on. It runs Centos. anyone got any tips on running rsync to sync it to a hard drive (on my local machine)?

Is there any way to use rsync but also have 'version history' of the files?

also I am doing this command

rsync -avz -e ssh user@hostname:/from/directory/on/remote/ /tmp/to/dir/on/local/

but when i cd /tmp/to/dir/on/local and do ls -lah it hasn't kept the file owner (the file owner is my own user on this local machine) . i am running OS X

Comment: The user ids must be identical on those machines or you'll get the uid from the source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re. keeping a version history; no, not just with rsync. You'd need to do this some other way. You could use rsync to copy the files for you but it will keep *one* directory in sync with *one* other directory.

One idea, you could rsync from A to B each night. Then rsync from B to B2 and B3 etc. on a daily basis - keeping daily backups of B, using rsync to make those copies.

Re. the file owner - if you're not root you can't `chown` files to another user. If you can run the command with `sudo`, that should preserve the owner then.